Is it the moral duty of the Hindu wife not to eat before her husband?
Is Sita the role model for this injunction or is it in some Dharma shastra?

I guess it's not about wife, any one cooking should serve others before serving himself/herself.

You should do what you believe is the right thing to do. As a lover, you would want to provide enough to your love even if it is at the cost of you not getting enough. Sita was in the jungles with limited resources so she perhaps offered food to her husband first so there is enough for him. At the same time the husband should also think about his wife's well being. In today's time, I believe couples should eat together. With all the distractions, it just makes sense to spend as much time with each other as possible.
